# How to implement a bit array in Modern Fortran?

Tags: fortran, bit-manipulation, hpc

I am new to Fortran 2008 and am trying to implement a Sieve of Atkin. In C++ I implemented this using a `std::bitset` but was unable to find anything in Fortran 2008 that serves this purpose.

Can anyone point me at any example code or explain an implementation strategy for one?

Answer (score 3):

Standard Fortran doesn't have a precise analogue of what I understand `std:bitset` to be -- though I grant you my understanding may be defective.  Generally, and if you want to stick to standard Fortran, you would use integers as sets of bits.  If one integer doesn't have enough bits for your purposes, use arrays of integers.  This does mean, though, that the responsibility for tracking where, say, the 307-th bit of your bitset is falls on you

Prior to the 2008 standard you have functions such as `bit_size`, `iand`, `ibset`, `btest` and others (see your compiler documentation or Google for language references, or try [the Intel Fortran documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/index.htm#GUID-FBF4E6D5-05DC-4A7C-8121-2EAA8940B33B.htm)) for bit manipulation.

If you are unfamiliar with Fortran's `boz` literals then familiarise yourself with them.  You can, for example, set the bits of an integer using a statement such as this

```
integer :: mybits
...
mybits = b'00000011000000100000000000001111'
```

With the `b edit descriptor` you can read and write binary literals too.  For example the statements

```
write(*,*) mybits
write(*,'(b32.32)') mybits
```

will produce the output

```
    50462735
00000011000000100000000000001111
```

If you can lay your hands on a modern-enough compiler then you will find that the 2008 standard added new bit-twiddling functions such as `bge`, `bgt`, `dshiftl`, `iall` and a whole lot more.  These are defined for input arguments which are integer arrays or integers, but I don't have any experience of using them to pass on.

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Is gfortran a "modern enough" compiler? Btw, I need to store 10 million bits for my Sieve implementation.

Comment: I don't know, it's not a compiler I ever use, but I'm sure that Google will help you find the answer to that question.

Comment: I don't know C's operations, but the Fortran procedures are well documented so you can probably determine this for yourself.

Comment: Gfortran is fast in implementing modern intrinsics (but use a recent version, of course). Just look in the online manual, for example http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DSHIFTL.html . You will find what the function does there also.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran has bit intrinsics for manipulating the bits of default integers. Bit arrays are straightforward to build off that...

Determine how many bits you need, divide by number of bits in default integer, allocate an integer array of default kind of the size you computed +1 if the modulo of the division was non-zero, and you're essentially done. The bit intrinsics are well covered in Metcalf and Reid.

Answer (score -2):

What you may want could look like:

```
program test
logical,allocatable:: flips(:)
...
allocate(flips(ntris),status=err)
call tris(ntris,...,flips)
...
end
subroutine tris(nnewtris, ...,flips)
logical flips(nnewtris)
...
if(flips(i)) then
...
end if
return
end
```

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to take the welcome [tour]. All answers benefit from some explanation, good answers normally do not just contain code. Note that short or code-only answers like this one are automatically selected for a special review as they are considered as potentially bad and several people have to look at them and decide if they are really bad or not. It is better to avoid this review.